# CSS in GTK - changing background color on button click

Tags: css, c, gtk

I'm trying to make application using GTK and styling it with CSS. I need to change button background on click. I need this for build in video player. When I press 'play' I want to mark that video is playing by changing 'play' button background, when I press 'pause' i want to 'play' button to change back to default and 'pause' button to change background. When pressing 'stop' both backgrounds should go back to default state. What is the best way to make such a behaviour?

I found function `gtk_widget_override_background_color`, but it's deprecated since version 3.16 and should not be used in newly-written code. 
I've also tried `button:focus` in css but it's not working correctly. It do change background color on click but when I click button that should not affect the background (for example changing volume) the background is changed to default.

EDIT.
I might have ask the question in kind of misleading way. `button:focus` works as intended but it doesn't fully suits my needs. Let me explain on example:
1. In the beggining (after choosing video) I have blank screen with message "press play"
[image]

2. Now I press play. The play button has added in css the focus
   Code from C:
   `gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(play_button), "play_button_1");`

And in css:

`button#play_button_1:focus {
     background-color: #67181B;
    }`

So when I press "play" the player looks like here:
[image]

3. It works fine until I use only buttons "play", "pause" and "stop". But when i press "+" or "-" (for volume control) the "play" button loses focus and it looks like this (the video is still playing, on the picture there is no focus on "-" button, it's hover. There is no coursor on the screenshot):
   [image]

So what I want to achieve is keeping "play" background changed as long as video is playing, no matter the focus on other buttons. I hope it's much more clearer now

Comment: Note that *NOT* all css attributes are respected by Gtk. Just a hand-few. Could you post the code with the css?

Comment: I might have written my question in kind of misleading way, button:focus works as intended but it doesn't suits my needs. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, not the best I suppose, but it's working. If someone has something better I will be happy to hear it.
I made more css files (specific files for every function that should trigger background change). So for example when i have "play" button I made file play.css:

```
button#play_button_1 {
background-color: #67181B;
}

button#pause_button_1 {
background-color: #D5D6DB;
}
```

and for button function I added

```
  GtkCssProvider *provider;
  GdkDisplay *display;
  GdkScreen *screen;

  provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
  display = gdk_display_get_default ();
  screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
  gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER   (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

  const gchar* path_to_css = "play.css";
  GError *error = 0;
  gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, g_file_new_for_path(path_to_css), &error);
```

Then I had to do the same (with other file) for pause button and once again load initial css file when pressing "stop" button.