# PyGObject - Change Checkbutton background dynamically

Tags: gtk, pygobject

I'm trying to programmatically change the color of the background of a CheckButtons.

For ComboBoxText, I've seen it done this way:

```
cbt.get_child().set_background_rgba(rgba=Gdk.RGBA(red=1.0, green=1.0, blue=1.0))
```

For CheckButtons, it seems I could do:

```
cbt.override_background_color(state, Gdk.RGBA(red=1.0, green=1.0, blue=1.0))
```

But this method is now deprecated, perhaps I could use `Gtk.render_background()`, but it seems I'd have to supply the background coordinates and dimension, and communicate the color via a Cairo context... is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

Looking the [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.override_background_color.html) for `override_background_color`, you can read:

> This function is not useful in the context of CSS-based rendering. If
> you wish to change the way a widget renders its background you should
> use a custom CSS style, through an application-specific
> `GtkStyleProvider` and a CSS style class. You can also override the
> default drawing of a widget through the `GtkWidget::draw` signal, and
> use Cairo to draw a specific color, regardless of the CSS style.

From what I read, you basically have two options (that are not deprecated, of course):

1. Use CSS. The `gtk3-demo` application as nice examples that you can run. Also, the Internet is filled with examples (see one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811589/css-in-gtk-changing-background-color-on-button-click), but there are many others), lots of which deal with the background color. You can also read [this guide](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-overview.html).
2. Override the `draw` signal. You would have to read about the [Cairo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811589/css-in-gtk-changing-background-color-on-button-click) and understand its basics. This is clearly more involved, in my opinion.